# Why doesn't my UIKeyboard disappear on resignfirstresponder

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is ridiculous, I cant't see whats wrong with my code. I hope anyone can help me to get 
it right. The problem is when resignfirstresponder fires it seems that another UIKeyboard appears, note the done button changes to an ordinary return button on the keyboard.

My testViewController.m file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "testViewController.h"
#define kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD 216.0
@interface testViewController ()
{
    float increase;
    int increases;
    UITextView *txt;
    UIView *vw;
    UIView *tvw;
    UITableView *tbl;
    UIButton *b;
}
@end

@implementation testViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    vw =[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-34, 320, 1000)];
    vw.backgroundColor =[UIColor blackColor];
    tbl =[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height-34)];
    txt =[UITextView new];
    txt.frame=CGRectMake(4, 4, 255, 25);
    [txt setScrollEnabled:NO];
    txt.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 4, 0, 0);
    [tbl setDelegate:self];
    [tbl setDataSource:self];
    [txt setDelegate:self];
    [txt setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    [self.view addSubview:tbl];
    [[txt layer] setCornerRadius:2.0f];
    [vw addSubview:txt];
    [self.view addSubview:vw];
    increases = 0;
    increase =23;
    txt.text =@"Give me text...";
    b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    b.frame = CGRectMake(263, 4, 53, 25);
    b.tag =1;
    [[b layer] setCornerRadius:2.0f];
    [[b layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(close:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [vw addSubview:b];
    b.backgroundColor =[UIColor grayColor];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
}
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    if(increase!=txt.contentSize.height) {
        CGRect rect = txt.frame;
        rect.size.height = txt.contentSize.height;
        textView.frame   = rect;
        CGRect bRect = b.frame;
        if(txt.frame.size.height<25){
            CGRect temp = txt.frame;
            temp.size.height =25;
            txt.frame =temp;
        }
        bRect.origin.y = txt.frame.size.height +4-25;
        b.frame = bRect;
        CGRect arect = self.view.frame;

        if(increase < txt.contentSize.height) {
            arect.origin.y -= 15;
            arect.size.height += 15;
            increases =increases+1;
        } else {
            arect.origin.y += 15;
            arect.size.height -= 15;
            increases =increases-1;
        }
        NSLog(@"%f",bRect.size.height);
        self.view.frame = arect;
        increase = txt.contentSize.height;
    }
}
-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    if (movedUp) {
        rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    } else {
        rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD+(increases*15);
        rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD+(increases*15);
        vw.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-34, 320, 1000);
        txt.frame = CGRectMake(4, 4, 255, 25);
        increase = 23;
        increases = 0;
        txt.text=@"";
    }
    self.view.frame = rect;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if  (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0) {
        txt.text =@"";
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }

}
-(void)close:sender {
    if(txt.isFirstResponder)
        [txt resignFirstResponder];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 100;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 60.0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.section];
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(txt.isFirstResponder)
        [txt resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

my testViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface testViewController :     UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>


@end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why exactly do you have a UITextView within a UITextView?  Specifically, vw has txt as a subview.

Comment: Thats a mistake it should have been a UIView!!! thanks

Comment: I'll submit it as the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a UITextView where you mean to have a UIView at the initialization of vw which is leading to you having a UITextView within a UITextView.